# notmuch mail unpacks zip

Tags: notmuch

When reading an email notmuch-(show)-mode unpacks zip files by default in my Emacs.

Is there a way to deactivate this behavior?

It's less of an issue for small zip-Files but I frequently send files that contain large binaries and this slows down the mail opening process considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the archives of the notmuch-mailing list.

I need to remove "application/zip" from `mm-inlined-types'.
Putting this in my init file solved it.

```
(setq mm-inlined-types (remove "application/zip" mm-inlined-types))
```